# How to initialize a value when creating an object in a static block

Tags: java

When creating the Racing class in ApplicationTest, I want to hand over the FixNumberBehavior class to the argument.

As shown below, to pass the argument to initialize FixNumberBehavior, but cannot pass the class field value to the static block.

The error message is as follows.

`Variable 'isMove' might not have been initialized`

FixNumberBehavior.java

```
public class FixNumberBehavior implements CarMoveBehavior {

  private final boolean isMove;
  private static FixNumberBehavior fixNumberBehavior;

  static {
      fixNumberBehavior = new FixNumberBehavior(); //error
  }

  public FixNumberBehavior(final boolean isMove) {
      this.isMove = isMove;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean moveBehavior() {
     return isMove;
  }
}
```

Racing.java

```
public class Racing {

private List<Car> cars;
private CarMoveBehavior carMoveBehavior;

public Racing(List<Car> cars, final CarMoveBehavior carMoveBehavior) {
    this.cars = cars;
    this.carMoveBehavior = carMoveBehavior;
}

public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void drive() {
    cars.stream()
        .forEach(car -> racingCondition(car));
}

private void racingCondition(Car car) {
    if (carMoveBehavior.moveBehavior()) {
        car.moveForward();
     }
  }
}
```

ApplicationTest

```
 @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"a,aa,aaa"})
    void fixRandomNumberTest(String one, String two, String three) {
        final List<Car> cars = Arrays.asList(new Car(one), new Car(two), new Car(three));
        Racing racing = new Racing(cars, new FixNumberBehavior(true));
        racing.drive();
        racing.drive();
        assertAll(
            () -> assertThat(cars.get(0).getStep()).isEqualTo(2),
            () -> assertThat(cars.get(1).getStep()).isEqualTo(2),
            () -> assertThat(cars.get(2).getStep()).isEqualTo(2)
        );
    }
```

How can I initialize an object in the static block?

Comment: Read the error message. It is nothing to do with your static block, but because you have a final field that your constructor doesn't initialise.

Comment: `isMove` is `final` - what means your noarg ctor is invalid.

Comment: @tgdavies I removed final keyword.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understood removing the final keyword. This is because initialization must be preceded.

Comment: Better to initialise the final field in the no-args constructor and keep it final, if immutable behaviour is what you want -- and presumably you had a reason for making it final to start with?

Comment: The reason why I used the final was because I wanted to initialize it once.

I understood what you said, and I solved the problem by applying it.

The method I chose was to erase the final keyword. @tgdavies

Comment: There is no obvious reason to use a static initializer block here. Just initialize directly on the field.

Comment: @AndyTurner
That's right.

The reason why I used the static field was that I thought It could clearly show the function with the class name.

I wonder what are some good examples of static methods.

Comment: @user16320675 I understand. I'll change it to creating an object instead of a static block.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `FixNumberBehavior` has a `final` field that must be set in the constructor, or in an assignment on the field definition line.

While there is a constructor that takes a value for that field, the static block is not using that constructor, but instead a no-arg constructor.

Pass the value for that final field (`isMove`) in the `new` statement.

Comment: I solved it by attaching static to the field.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to overcomplicate things by

- providing no-argument constructor when you already have constructor in which you let *client* decide if created instance of `FixNumberBehavior` will set `isMove` to true or false.
- changing ([in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70912698)) `isMove` from being `final` to being `static`. Those two keywords have different purpose:

  - `final` prevents reassigning new value to it
  - `static` makes this field a *class* field, not *instance* field, so even if you create two instances of `FixNumberBehavior` there will be only *one* `isMove` variable which they both will use (so you can't preserve in one instance state like `isMove=true` and in other state `isMove=false`).

What you are looking for is probably simply

```
public class FixNumberBehavior implements CarMoveBehavior {

    private final boolean isMove;

    private static FixNumberBehavior fixNumberBehavior = new FixNumberBehavior(true);
                                                     //set value you want here ^^^^

    public FixNumberBehavior(final boolean isMove) {
        this.isMove = isMove;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveBehavior() {
        return isMove;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by attaching static to the field.

Objects created in the static block are not identified when compiling. Therefore, the argument value to be transferred to the object you create in the static block must also be processed statistically.

```java
package racingcar.model.domain;

public class FixNumberBehavior implements CarMoveBehavior {

    private static boolean isMove;
    private static FixNumberBehavior fixNumberBehavior;

    static {
        fixNumberBehavior = new FixNumberBehavior(isMove);
    }

    private FixNumberBehavior() {

    }

    public static FixNumberBehavior getInstance(){
        return fixNumberBehavior;
    }

    public FixNumberBehavior(final boolean isMove) {
        this.isMove = isMove;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveBehavior() {
        return isMove;
    }
}
```

Comment: it may work, but making a field `static` just because it works is a (bad) workaround. It should be done so if it reflects the use case, data design, Object Oriented concepts, ... (if the field should be a class member only than it should be declared `static`) ((I did not understand the second paragraph at all))

Comment: All your instances now share a single `isMove` field.

Comment: I understood. Single tone means nothing anymore. @Boris the Spider